# Identify bordered sections on standardized images and crop accordingly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision, ocr, python-imaging-library

I apologize for newbie mistakes - I am a true Python newbie.

A little insight on the image at hand and why I'm parsing information:
The attached image is a UB-04 form (or CMS-1450) and it's a uniform billing form used by institutional providers for claim billing. Although it was developed by The Centers for Medicare and Medicaid (CMS), it has become the standard form used by all insurance carriers.

[UB04 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ1Vu.png)

I receive these forms as PDFs where each provider has filled information with regards to treatment they gave in order to receive payments by the government or private insurer. I was manually extracting information from these PDFs but built a process to make this faster.  However, this process is not robust enough and I wish to improve it, if possible.

I've added a sample of this form with some text I randomly edited in.

```
#I need to clean up these imports -_-
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image as IMG
import PIL
import cv2
from wand.image import Image
import PythonMagick
import pandas as pd
import operator
import functools
import csv
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import xlsxwriter
from random import randint
import glob
import datetime

# Choose PDF series to convert to images - parse the images page by page
pdfclaimtoconvert = "UB04 PDF"

with(Image(filename=pdfclaimtoconvert+".pdf",resolution=200)) as source:
    images=source.sequence
    pages=len(images)
    for i in range(pages):
        Image(images[i]).save(filename='Cropped Images/'+pdfclaimtoconvert+str(i)+'.tiff')

# Loop through all pages
for page in range(0,pages):
    # Select page number to parse text from
    pagenumber = str(page)

    filetoworkon = 'Cropped Images/'+pdfclaimtoconvert+pagenumber+'.tiff'

    # Read & Write image back as tiff
    image = cv2.imread(filetoworkon)
    cv2.imwrite("test.tiff",image)

    # Convert Red Pixels to white (this helps eliminate noise for tesseract to work properly)
    image_tiff = IMG.open('test.tiff')
    # load the pixel info
    width, height = image_tiff.size
    for x in range(width):
       for y in range(height):
           r,g,b = image_tiff.getpixel((x,y))
           if r > 130 and b < 240:
               image_tiff.putpixel((x, y), (255,255,255))
    image_tiff.save('test.tiff')
```

This upcoming section is my main hurtle right now - Ideally, rather than strictly specifying a segmentation, I would like to incept a process where I can identify each one of those borders (for example top left would be border space 1, border space next to it would be border space 2 etc) - I assume there may be hundreds on this document), and then I can run a script that will segment on those borders exactly and parse information as needed.

```
    #Read Image and Crop relevant sections
    img = cv2.imread('test.tiff')

    crop_img = img[20:170, 20:530] # Address
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test1.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[200:240, 20:530] #patient name
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test2.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[260:310, 20:205] #birthdate
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test3.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[400:570, 20:860] #Payer Address
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test4.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[600:1340, 20:120] #Treatment Codes
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test5.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[600:1340, 121:620] #Treatment Descriptions
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test6.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[600:1340, 620:910] #HCPCS
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test7.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[600:1340, 910:1059] #Service Dates
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test8.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[600:1340, 1059:1220] #Service Units
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test9.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[600:1340, 1214:1365] #Service Charges
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test10.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[600:1340, 1355:1420] #Service Charges decimals
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test11.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[1400:1510,20:480] #Payer Name
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test12.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[20:75,1070:1580] #Patient Control No
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test13.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[75:105,1070:1400] #Med Rec
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test14.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[130:175,1015:1220] #Fed Tax No
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test15.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[135:175,1220:1510] #Statement from and To
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test16.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[1340:1372,900:1050] #Creation Date
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test17.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[1662:1700,630:1160] #Document Control No
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test18.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[1340:1372,130:280] #Pages #1
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test19.tiff", crop_img)

    crop_img = img[1340:1372,280:500] #Pages #2
    cv2.imwrite("Cropped Images/test20.tiff", crop_img)

    # Use Tesseract to Read text for each of the crops - input in a list
    # Separate numerical exrtactions from mixed or string so that we can force tesseract to recognize them as digits
    TextExtract = {}

    numericals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
    nonnumericals = [9, 10, 11, 19, 20]

    for i in numericals:
        img = IMG.open(
            'YOURPATH/Cropped Images/test' + str(i) + '.tiff')
        img.load()
        TextExtract["test{0}".format(i)] = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='-psm 6')

    for i in nonnumericals:
        img = IMG.open(
            'YOURPATH/Cropped Images/test' + str(i) + '.tiff')
        img.load()
        TextExtract["test{0}".format(i)] = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,

                                                                config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789 -psm 6')

    # Split each item in dictionary by page break
    ParsedText = {}

    for i in range(1, 21):
        ParsedText["test{0}".format(i)] = TextExtract['test' + str(i)].split('\n')

    # Delete empty list items
    for x in range(1, 21):
        ParsedText['test' + str(x)] = [i for i in ParsedText['test' + str(x)] if i != '']

    # Collapse lists into single values
    CollapsedLists = {}

    collapsablelist=(1,2,3,4,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)

    for i in range(1,21):
        if i in collapsablelist:
            CollapsedLists["test{0}".format(i)] = ' '.join(ParsedText['test'+str(i)])
        else:
            CollapsedLists["test{0}".format(i)] = ParsedText['test'+str(i)]

    # Extraction list
    extractionlist = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)

    # Create empty Pandas Dataframe
    extractionframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7', 'test8'
        , 'test9', 'test10', 'test11', 'test12', 'test13', 'test14', 'test15', 'test16'
        , 'test17', 'test18', 'test19', 'test20'
                                            ])

    # Populate dataframe
    for x in extractionlist:
        if isinstance(CollapsedLists['test' + str(x)], list) is False:
            try:
                extractionframe.loc[1, 'test' + str(x)] = CollapsedLists['test' + str(x)]
            except:
                pass
        else:
            for i in range(len(CollapsedLists['test' + str(x)])):
                extractionframe.loc[i + 1, 'test' + str(x)] = CollapsedLists['test' + str(x)][i]

    # Populate source
    extractionframe.loc[1, 'source'] = pdfclaimtoconvert + '_page_' + pagenumber

    # Fill NaN values forward
    extractionframe = extractionframe.fillna(method='ffill')

    #Convert to excel formula in order to preserve any leading zeroes
    extractionframe = extractionframe.applymap(str)
    extractionframe2 = '="'+extractionframe+'"'

    # Export to excel
    with open('Claim Data Extractions.csv', 'a') as f:
        extractionframe2.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of contour analysis. Most of the hard work is encapsulated in OpenCV and you have a terrific example to inspire you [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/).

Comment: That looks very helpful! I will try to work through it and hopefully devise a solution based on it!